# Rails Modify Array in Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops

I thought this would be a simple task, but I'm finding it difficult to make Rails do what I want.

I've got an array of dates.

So I thought that something like this would work:

```
  def index
    @datetimes = Books.all.map(&:checkouts).flatten.map(&:out_date)
    @datetimes.each do |c|
      c.to_date
    end
  end
```

Then I can just call this in my view:

```
%ul
-@datetimes.each do |c|
    %li=c
```

How do I modify each key in the array? What am I missing here?

Thanks, so much for being nice to new, novice, and ignorant hobbyists like myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.each` doesn't modify the caller.  It simply loops through.  You could change the controller action to just this:

```
@datetimes = Books.all.map(&:checkouts).flatten.map{|e| e.out_date.to_date}
```

You might also want to explore including :checkouts in your Books query to avoid N+1 queries.  Or perhaps doing something like this maybe.

```
Checkout.where("book_id is not null").map{|e| e.out_date.to_date}
```

Comment: Philip...I'm ruby-novice level. I've heard of N+1 queries, but don't fully understand the concept. Can you elaborate? Should I move my nested model to a separate collection? Would that make things easier?

Comment: Additionally...I know this wasn't the original question. But what if I wanted to do math stuff to each value? Like add a year, or find the difference between that date and another?

Comment: @KevinBrown See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations for info on N+1.  If you want to do math to each value simply do it inside the last map{}.  That is `...map{|e| (e.out_date + 1.year).to_date}`